# Pygame functions having two brackets

Tags: python, function, pygame

Why does pygame.dispay.set_mode(()) and other similar functions has two braces instead of one and why it isnt working if i just put only one brace?

Comment: This function takes a tuple as an argument and the second pair of parens enclose the tuple values. If you remove parens then it's two separate values when a method is expecting only one tuple object.

Comment: You should give details for "Isn't working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display mode gets a tuple with two items to describe the resolution for the render-screen. And a tuple will be defined by

```
pygame.dispay.set_mode(size=(640, 280))
```

When using the default you just use the empty tuple definition

```
pygame.dispay.set_mode(size=(0, 0))
```

I have found this here [PyGame Documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)

Answer (score 1):

> This function takes a tuple as an argument and the second pair of parens enclose the tuple values. – pavel

So when you add two brackets, you are passing a tuple